# System.Int32 metadata does not show inheritance from System.Valuetype

Tags: c#, types

As we know all structure type inherit from System.Value Type & System.Value Type derived from System.Object, but metadata of System.Int32 does not shoe inheritance structure, why?

what does it mean value types are derived implicitly from the System.Value Type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by metadata not showing it. Reflection does - `Console.WriteLine(typeof(Int32).BaseType.FullName);` prints `System.ValueType`. MSDN doesn't show it because it clearly states [Int32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the same as saying it is a value type

Comment: when i see inside of an int variable (by go to definition) public struct Int32 does not inherit from any System.Value type that is what i am confused please correct  if i m am wrong at any point

Comment: Indeed - when you create a value type, you don't inherit from `ValueType` explicitly - you create a `struct`. Go to Def is just showing how the source code would look, not the _actual_ reflected compiled code, hence `public struct Int32 {}`

Comment: It mean when we compile the System.Int32 variable would automatically derive from System.ValueType is that right?

Comment: The System.Int32 declaration has very little to do with the way an *int* is used at runtime.  It is the representation of a *boxed* integer.  The boxing conversion is what makes it *look* like it derives from System.Object.  Quacks-like-a-duck typing.

Comment: ya now i got it thanks,One last question why we call System.ValueType & System.Object to be base class as reflection also says same way